# How to plot 5 subplots sharing x and y axes in Python

Tags: python

As in the title, I have 5 plots in Python I want to produce. How would I plot all 5 of these so that they share the same axes? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "plot"?  Do you have a means to generate a single "plot"?

Comment: Yes I can plot an individual graph for a set of data. But I want to put all 5 of these graphs (all 5 of these data sets) on the same page (not so all the 5 data sets are on one graph, but instead having 5 graphs on the same 'page')

Comment: What is a page? What libraries do you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subplot` with the `sharex` and `sharey` options. Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = np.zeros((5, 100))
for i in range(5):
    y[i] = x**i

ax = []    
kw = {}
for i in range(5):
    if i > 0:
        kw ={'sharex': ax[0], 'sharey': ax[0]}
    ax.append(pl.subplot(3, 2, i+1, **kw))
    ax[i].plot(x, y[i])
```

Comment: Thats excellent thanks! Is there a way to change the location of the graphs? e.g. in a 2 x 2 set up with another at the bottom?